# what is the difference between randomString.decode("utf-8") VS str(randomString, "utf-8")?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, python-3.5

what is the difference between randomString.decode("utf-8") VS str(randomString, "utf-8") ?

 I see they r same but when I tried them they turn out to be different !!!

> >>> randomString = "Hello World" 
>   >>> str(randomString) 
>   \'Hello World' 
>   >>> randomString.decode("utf-8") 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "< input >", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
>   >>> randomString.encode()
>   b'Hello World'
>   >>> bString = randomString.encode()
>   >>> bString.decode()
>   'Hello World'
>   >>> str(bString)
>   "b'Hello World'"

and I don't really understand the difference between the normal string and the byte string?
help plz!

Comment: Try `randomString = "Hello World ěščřž" ; print (randomString.encode("utf-8"))` with some non-`ASCII` characters. Note **encode** is string to bytes conversion and **decode** is bytes to string.

Comment: ok that gave me the Bytes: __b'Hello World \xc4\x9b\xc5\xa1\xc4\x8d\xc5\x99\xc5\xbe'__ ,, but i'm confused with the decoding part ... does str(randomBytes, "utf-8") decode it like randomBytes.decode("utf-8") does ?

Comment: `print (str(randomString.encode(),"utf-8") == randomString.encode().decode())` returns **True** so what are you asking for?

Comment: thanks @JosefZ that answers my Q ^_^ there is no difference !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [(*Python*) Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) and [`str()` in detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> ```
> class str(object='')
> class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
> ```
>
> Return a string version of object. If object is not provided, returns
>   the empty string. Otherwise, the behavior of `str()` depends on whether
>   encoding or errors is given, as follows.
>
> If neither encoding nor errors is given, `str(object)` returns
>   `object.__str__()`, which is the “informal” or nicely printable string
>   representation of object. For string objects, this is the string
>   itself. If object does not have a `__str__()` method, then `str()` falls
>   back to returning `repr(object)`.
>
> If at least one of encoding or errors is given, object should be a
>   [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) (e.g. `bytes` or `bytearray`). In this case, if object
>   is a *bytes* (or *bytearray*) object, then `str(bytes, encoding, errors)`
>   **is equivalent to** `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`. Otherwise, the bytes object underlying the buffer object is obtained before calling
>   `bytes.decode()`. See [Binary Sequence Types — bytes, bytearray,
>   memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq) and [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects) for information on buffer objects.

Please note that there are not given all links explicitly in above quoted text.

**Example** (Python 3.5.1):

```
>>>
>>> randomString = 'latin, ελληνικά, кириллица'
>>>
>>> print (str(randomString.encode(),"utf-8") == randomString.encode().decode())
True
>>>
```